# filter url in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, filter

current Url:
http://localhost:8000/filter-results?country_id=1&education_level_id=&employment_type_id=&language_id=&profession_id=&religion_id=1

how I wanted to looks like:
http://localhost:8000/filter-results?country_id=1&religion_id=1

how can I do that.
more details:
I have a filter view as a part of the home page which have 6 combobox for selecting a country, education level etc.. then in the controller i'm filtering the person based on these data and retriving the data to display it in worker list view.

the function responsible for filtering :

```
    public function filterResults(Request $request)
    {
        // Retrieve filter criteria from the request
        $countryId        = $request->input('country_id');
        $educationLevelId = $request->input('education_level_id');
        $employmentTypeId = $request->input('employment_type_id');
        $languageId       = $request->input('language_id');
        $personId         = $request->input('person_id');
        $professionId     = $request->input('profession_id');
        $religionId       = $request->input('religion_id');

        // Build the query based on the filter criteria
        $query = Person::query();

        // Add conditions based on the presence of each filter parameter
        if ($countryId) {
            $query->where('country_id', $countryId);
        }
        if ($educationLevelId) {
            $query->where('education_level_id', $educationLevelId);
        }
        if ($employmentTypeId) {
            $query->where('employment_type_id', $employmentTypeId);
        }
        if ($languageId) {
            $query->whereHas('languages', function ($query) use ($languageId) {
                $query->where('language_id', $languageId);
            });
        }
        if ($personId) {
            $query->where('person_id', $personId);
        }
        if ($professionId) {
            $query->where('profession_id', $professionId);
        }
        if ($religionId) {
            $query->where('religion_id', $religionId);
        }

        // Eager load relationships
        $query->with(['country', 'educationLevel', 'employmentType', 'languages', 'profession', 'religion']);

        // Paginate the results with 10 items per page
        $perPage = 10;

        // Resolve the current page from the query parameters or default to 1
        $currentPage = $request->input('page') ?? 1;

        // Get the results
        $filteredResults = $query->paginate($perPage, ['*'], 'page', $currentPage);

        // Get all countries and professions (if needed for the view)
        $additionalData = [
            'countries' => Country::all(),
            'educationLevels' => EducationLevel::all(),
            'employmentTypes' => EmploymentType::all(),
            'languages' => Language::all(),
            'professions' => Profession::all(),
            'religions' => Religion::all(),
        ];

        return view('workerList.index', [
            'filteredResults' => $filteredResults,
        ] + $additionalData);
    }

    /**
     * Build query with filters.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder $query
     * @param array $filters
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
     */
    private function buildQueryWithFilters($query, array $filters)
    {
        foreach ($filters as $key => $value) {
            $query->when($value, function ($query) use ($key, $value) {
                return $query->where($key, $value);
            });
        }

        return $query;
    }

    /**
     * Get additional data for the view.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    private function getAdditionalData()
    {
        return [
            'countries' => Country::all(),
            'educationLevels' => EducationLevel::all(),
            'employmentTypes' => EmploymentType::all(),
            'languages' => Language::all(),
            'professions' => Profession::all(),
            'religions' => Religion::all(),
        ];
    }
```

route:

```
Route::get('/filter-results', [FilterController::class, 'filterResults'])->name('filter.results');
```

blade html:

```
<form method="get" action="{{ route('filter.results') }}" class="container p-4 rounded">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <label for="country">Country:</label>
            <select class="form-control input-lg b-0 br-1 border-light rounded-0" name="country_id" id="country">
                <option value="">All</option>
                @foreach ($countries as $country)
                    <option value="{{ $country->id }}" >{{ $country->name }}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <label for="educationLevel">Education level:</label>
            <select class="form-control input-lg b-0 br-1 border-light rounded-0" name="education_level_id" id="educationLevel">
                <option value="">All</option>
                @foreach ($educationLevels as $educationLevel)
                    <option value="{{ $educationLevel->id }}">{{ $educationLevel->name }}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <label for="employmentType">Employment type:</label>
            <select class="form-control input-lg b-0 br-1 border-light rounded-0" name="employment_type_id" id="employmentType">
                <option value="">All</option>
                @foreach ($employmentTypes as $employmentType)
                    <option value="{{ $employmentType->id }}">{{ $employmentType->name }}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row mt-3">
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <label for="language">Language:</label>
            <select class="form-control input-lg b-0 br-1 border-light rounded-0" name="language_id" id="language">
                <option value="">All</option>
                @foreach ($languages as $language)
                    <option value="{{ $language->id }}">{{ $language->name }}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <label for="profession">Profession:</label>
            <select class="form-control input-lg b-0 br-1 border-light rounded-0" name="profession_id" id="profession">
                <option value="">All</option>
                @foreach ($professions as $profession)
                    <option value="{{ $profession->id }}">{{ $profession->name }}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <label for="religion">Religion:</label>
            <select class="form-control input-lg b-0 br-1 border-light rounded-0" name="religion_id" id="religion">
                <option value="">All</option>
                @foreach ($religions as $religion)
                    <option value="{{ $religion->id }}">{{ $religion->name }}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row mt-3">
        <div class="col-12">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Find workers</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Share the code which you tried

Comment: Is this url creating dynamically

Comment: you mean the controller code? or the route?

Comment: share both the code

Comment: take a look now, and if you need more details ask pls

Comment: Add the html and js code in filter view need to create url based on the selection

Comment: i'm not using javascript for that. I will provide you with the html just a sec.

Comment: You might want to solve this by adding an event listener to the form submission in order to intercept it, iterate over inputs and only include those parameters, as well as modifying form action parameter attribute dynamically. @Rayzel

Comment: i had that idea but it wasnt very clear to me how would that work with laravel. In addition i was wondering if there is a direct solution with laravel without including javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I solved it using vanilla JS:

```
function submitForm() {
    let countryId = document.getElementById("country").value;
    let educationLevelId = document.getElementById("educationLevel").value;
    let employmentTypeId = document.getElementById("employmentType").value;
    let languageId = document.getElementById("language").value;
    let professionId = document.getElementById("profession").value;
    let religionId = document.getElementById("religion").value;

    let filteredUrl = filterResultsRoute + "?";
    if (countryId) filteredUrl += "country_id=" + countryId + "&";
    if (educationLevelId)
        filteredUrl += "education_level_id=" + educationLevelId + "&";
    if (employmentTypeId)
        filteredUrl += "employment_type_id=" + employmentTypeId + "&";
    if (languageId) filteredUrl += "language_id=" + languageId + "&";
    if (professionId) filteredUrl += "profession_id=" + professionId + "&";
    if (religionId) filteredUrl += "religion_id=" + religionId + "&";

    filteredUrl = filteredUrl.replace(/&$/, "");

    document.getElementById("filterForm").action = filteredUrl;
    document.getElementById("filterForm").submit();

    window.location.href = filteredUrl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use js to do this

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Find workers</button>
```

change this to

```
<button type="submit" id="form_submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Find workers</button>

//add is to form id="form_filter"
//add this in the script file

$("#form_submit").click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
  var params_data = {}
   if($("#country").val()) {
    params_data.country_id = $("#country").val();
   }

   if($("#educationLevel").val()) {
    params_data.education_level_id = $("#educationLevel").val();
   }

   if($("#employmentType").val()) {
    params_data.employment_type_id = $("#employmentType").val();
   }
   
window.location.href = $("#form_filter").attr('action')+'?'+$.param(params_data);
});


Basic idea is to change get data using js
```

Comment: I took your approach idea and coded it in vanilla JS because I'm not that good in jQuery (i guess the language you are using) thank you so much